# Geometric application of $AM-GM$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality, contest-math

> What is the maximum possible area of a rectangle inscribed in the ellipse with equation $9x^2+16y^2=144$?

This was instructed to be solved using $AM-GM$. I managed to get the right answer by the following approach.

$$\frac{9x^2+16y^2}{2} \geqslant  \sqrt{144} =12$$
$$\Rightarrow 9x^2+16y^2 \geqslant 24.$$

But I know I'm not using the inequality as I should although the right answer seemed to be $24$.

The correct way would have been something like this I think

$$\frac{9x^2+16y^2}{2} \geqslant  \sqrt{9x^2 \cdot 16y^2} =12xy$$
$$\Rightarrow 9x^2+16y^2 \geqslant 24xy$$

but I don't see how I can make this work, dividing by $xy$ only results in

$$\frac{9x}{y} + \frac{16y}{x} \geqslant 24.$$

What should I do here?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $|xy|$ is the area in the first quadrant. $|xy|=\frac{A}{4}$ where $A$ is our desired area.

Hence the area is bounded by $$\frac{144}{2}=\frac{9x^2+16y^2}{2} \ge 12|xy|=3A$$

$$A \le \frac{12^2}{2\cdot 3}=24$$

After which, you just have to show that this value is attainable.

Answer (score 0):

$144=9x^2+16y^2≥2\sqrt{144(xy)^2}=24(xy) \rightarrow xy≤\frac{144}{24}=6$$

Now, it the vertices of the rectangle are $(x,y),(x,-y),(-x,y),(-x,-y)$, then the area of the rectangle is $A=4xy≤6×4=24$. So, the highest value  of area of the rectangle is $24$.

Comment: Is it obvious that the largest rectangle inscribable in the ellipse has sides parallel to its axes?